# Good HTTP library for Objective-C / iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, http

**UPDATE:** this question is obviously obsolete (see the date). I recommend just using modern iOS7 features like NSURLSession. The question is preserved for historical accuracy, I guess.

What's a good HTTP library for (desktop Cocoa and) iPhone? Should just have a good interface to the basics like HTTP headers, get/post values (request string creation, URL encoding/decoding), sync and async requests... preferably pure Obj-C implementation. NSURL* is somewhat lacking.

Comment: I didn't find anything useful.  What are you looking for that is lacking with NSURL?

Comment: darren - for example, easy way to building POST requests (body values) from a set of parameter keys and values. NSURL doesn't give that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out [All Seeing Interactives ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Comment: This and TTURLRequest both look neat.

Comment: A quick look on [library documentation](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and [github](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/) reveals that the library is no more actively developed neither by the original developer nor a community and it does have [serious issues](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/pull/345).

Answer (score 3):

How about what's already built into Cocoa in the forms of [`NSURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLRequest) and it's subclass [`NSMutableURLRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?  You'll probably also get to use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) along with it...

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with the Three20 Project's [TTURLRequest.](http://joehewitt.com/post/the-three20-project/)
It's a genericized version of the UI Elements used in the Facebook App.

Comment: Is the official branch app-store safe yet?

Comment: In http://three20.info/ there's an indicator of the current Three20 App Store status, and at the time of this writing it's marked "safe".

Answer (score 1):

Setting the post parameters in the HTTP body is pretty straight forward with NSMutableURLRequest, you can wrap it in a convenience method via a category if that's more desirable, similar to the OAuth library on google code:

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/obj-c1/OAuthConsumer/NSMutableURLRequest+Parameters.m

Checkout the setParameters override, specifically these lines:

```
NSData *postData = [encodedParameterPairs dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        [self setHTTPBody:postData];
        [self setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [self setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Of course, you'll want to adjust the content-type header for the specific content of your post body (e.g. json, xml, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-quick-tip-interacting-with-web-services--mobile-10278      there is 3 libs. you can use...i think  AFNetworking is good.